# io.imsave() does not create multiple image files

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to run a while loop at the end of which an image is created and saved. Unfortunately, each loop updates the previously saved image file instead of creating a new image file. So at the end of a while loop that runs 5 times (and should create 5 separate images), I end up with a while loop that runs 5 times but creates only one image that updates 5 times.
Here is my related code block:

```
i = 5
    while i > 0:
        layer_name = 'pool'+str(i)
    # Number of output classes of model being used
        nb_classes = 1000

        cam3 = grad_cam(x, vgg, sess, predicted_class, layer_name, nb_classes)

        img = img.astype(float)
        img /= img.max()

    # Superimposing the visualization with the image.
        new_img = img+3*cam3
        new_img /= new_img.max()

    # Display and save
        #io.imshow(new_img)
        #plt.show()
        io.imsave(FLAGS.output, new_img)



        i = i-1
        print (i)
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated since I have been stuck on this for a few hours now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I do not know io.imsave, but i guess it comes from:
[skimage.io.imsave](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imsave)?

So i guess you should have a new filename in every iteration?

Comment: yes it comes from skimage.io.imsave, so if i change my: io.imsave(FLAGS.output, new_img) to io.imsave(file_name(i), new_img), I end up with an error that says file_name not defined. The point is, it doesn't seem to be creating a new file on every iteration, instead it just saves on the existing FLAGS.output path

Comment: Documentation says fname is of type str, so it should be `"my_filename" + i`